# Schedule simple python script to run each day on IBM Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I have a simple python script. I want to get it to run each day at 12pm. However i can't seem to find a way to do this on the workload scheduler in IBM Bluemix. If somebody could guide me through the process, that would be great.

I cant seem to find where to upload or refer to the script.

I already have a flask app successfully working on bluemix with no issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a setup.py in your apps home directory? That will automatically enable the python_buildback. You could use the starter application as a template here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/python/index.html . See here for using python apps in general https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cfapps/starter_app_usage.html?pos=6

Comment: I dont follow what you mean. I dont know what home directory your talking about :'(

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at [OpenWhisk on Bluemix and the alarm package](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_alarms.html#openwhisk_catalog_alarm). It allows, similar to cron, to fire periodic events. [OpenWhisk](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/) supports Python scripts. It is simpler than using Workload scheduler.